# How to set own image for the cursor for drag operation

Tags: eclipse-rap

It is possible to set/change the image for the cursor for a drag-operatio this way:

```java
Listener listener = new Listener() {
  public void handleEvent(Event event) {
    switch (event.type) {
      case SWT.MouseDown:
        moveComposite.setCursor(Display.getCurrent().getSystemCursor(SWT.CURSOR_WAIT));
        ...
      }
  ...

moveComposite.addListener(SWT.MouseDown, listener);
```

But in this case only standard cursors can be set.

Is it possible to set an own image for a cursor for a drag operation?
Either in a CSS for a named Control, programmatically for a named Control or as an alternative globally changing the standard cursors.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround for the missing API (see Rüdiger's answer), you could try to set a custom variant while dragging:

```
moveComposite.setData(RWT.CUSTOM_VARIANT, "dragging");
```

and configure a custom cursor for this variant in CSS like this:

```
.dragging {
  cursor: url(resources/dragging.gif)
}
```

Comment: This is working fine for a Button, Label, ... but not for a Composite. Also the documentation "RWT Theming Reference" does not mention a CSS Property called cursor.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this now with the help of a ClientListener. Because SWT.DragDetect is not supported I have to use SWT.MouseMove

```java
final private String scriptCodeMouseMove =
    "var handleEvent = function(event) {\n"
  + "    if(window.event.which==1) {"
  + "        document.body.style.cursor = 'url(...url to image...),, auto';\n"
  + "    } else {"
  + "        document.body.style.cursor = 'auto';\n"
  + "    }"
  + "}";

composite.addListener(SWT.MouseMove, new ClientListener(scriptCodeMouseMove));
```

Not really nice, but it works for me.
This way the cursor also changes if the Mouse-Button is pressed without doing a drag-Operation.

I'm really no JavaScript developer, so I'm sure there is much better JavaScript-Code which can do the same stuff.

Btw.: I wanted to use event.button from the ClientScrpting API, but it always returned 1, also if no mouse button was pressed (or 3 doing a right click).

Answer (score 0):

SWT/Desktop has `Cursor` constructors that accept `ImageData` like

```
Cursor( Device device, ImageData source, ... )
```

but RWT does not provide this API and hence cannot display custom cursors.

See also this open enhancement request: [Bug 295806 - Cursor constructor with ImageData is missing](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=295806)

**EDIT:**

Without having tired myself, you may be able to work around this limitation with CSS and [*custom variants*](https://www.eclipse.org/rap/developers-guide/devguide.php?topic=theming.html#variants).

Define a CSS rule which matches all widgets with a custom variant `customCursor` and changes the cursor to the desired one:

```
.customCursor {
  cursor: url( ... );
}
```

Now you can assign the custom variant to the outermost shell (assuming that there is a maximized shell that covers the entire display).

```java
Shell outermostShell = ...
outermostShell.setData( SWT.CUSTOM_VARIANT, "customCursor" );
```

If CSS cursor aren't *inherited* from parent to child controls, you may need to iterate over the widget hierarchy and set the custom variant explicitly for all controls that should show the custom cursor.

Comment: I know from this missing constructor, but not from this bug, thanks.  
My hope was there is some 'workaround'. For example setting the Cursor via CSS to a Control and getting it with control.getCursor() or any other idea.